# Is it possible to use Web Link to get the ASP.NET MVC which generated some piece of HTML?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, browser-link

is it possible to use Browser Link to get the exact piece of ASP.NET MVC which generated an html tag?

Imagine I've some divs. Some identified by css, some by their id, some by the id of their parents. Usually there isn't an organic way to pass from the rendered page to the element which has genereted it. I need to find the piece of View wich genereted an html tag

Comment: Sometimes.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Imagine I've some divs. Some identified by css, some by their id, some by the id of their parents. Usually there isn't an organic way to pass from the rendered page to the element which has genereted it. I need to find the piece of View wich genereted an html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to answer by myself...

I found it's possible through Browser Link + Web Essential pressing CTRL + ALT + I or CTRL + ALT + D. Visual Studio will select the corrisponding piece of ASP.NET code that generated the HTML code.